# How do I make unattended-upgrades email me every time it runs?

Tags: debian, upgrade, unattended, automatic-updates

How do I get unattended-upgrades to email me every time it runs, even if there are no packages that need updating?

When there are upgrades they are applied and I am emailed, so the configuration is at least partially right.

**System details and configuration**

unattended-upgrades is running on my Raspberry Pi 3b, which is running stretch:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
```

I installed `unattended-upgrades`, `ssmtp`, `bsd-mailx`, `apt-listchanges`.

Removing my email address, the un-commented content of `50unattended-upgrades` is:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        "o=Raspbian, a=stable";
        "o=Raspberry Pi Foundation, a=stable";
};

Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
};

Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "xxx@xxx.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "false";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

The content of `20auto-upgrades` is:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
APT::Periodic::Verbose "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
```

**System behaviour**

On June 10 unattended-upgrades ran, applied a number of upgrades and emailed me.

On June 11, unattended-upgrades ran, there were no upgrades or updates and I did not receive an email. Reviewing unattended-upgrades.log I see:

```
2019-06-10 06:13:06,708 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2019-06-10 06:13:06,710 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2019-06-10 06:13:06,711 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2019-06-10 06:13:06,712 INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Raspbian, a=stable', 'o=Raspberry Pi Foundation, a=stable']
2019-06-10 06:14:48,222 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: ffmpeg libav-tools libavcodec57 libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libcupsfilters1 libpostproc54 libswresample2 libswscale4 omxplayer
2019-06-10 06:14:48,223 INFO Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log'
2019-06-10 06:24:41,720 INFO All upgrades installed
2019-06-10 06:24:55,243 INFO Packages that are auto removed: 'ffmpeg libav-tools libavdevice57 libsdl2-2.0-0'
2019-06-10 06:25:20,072 INFO Packages were successfully auto-removed
2019-06-11 06:45:06,671 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2019-06-11 06:45:06,674 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2019-06-11 06:45:06,675 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2019-06-11 06:45:06,676 INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Raspbian, a=stable', 'o=Raspberry Pi Foundation, a=stable']
2019-06-11 06:45:24,801 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

Additionally, reviewing the gmail account I use to send the unattended-upgrades email I see a sent email for the 10th of June but none for the 11th.

Additionally, I have just run

```
"Test email" | mail -s "Test Mail" xxx@xxx.com
```

And received this at the destination address.

Based on all of this I conclude that unattended-upgrades is not mailing me unless there are upgrades to apply. However I want an email each day, whether there are any upgrades or not. How can I get this?

(and yes, I could just set a cron job to mail me a tail of the log file, but I'd like to do it via unattended-upgrades and a confirmation "I ran but didn't need to do anything" seems like the kind of feature it would support)

Comment: Your `Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins` looks unusual and your `APT::Periodic` configs might be relevant here. Use `apt-config dump | grep` to avoid confusion from multiple files. BTW, are you sure you should not be using stock Debian?

Comment: @anx thanks for your comment - I have used the script [from this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/792621/110172) to clarify what Allowed-Origins I need. Doing a dry run now that finds some updates to do. I'm going to leave it to run in true unattended fashion tonight to confirm it works or identify other issues, then update this Q&A with more info or post a separate question as makes sense.

Comment: @anx - I have updated my question, unattended-upgrades does email me if there are upgrades to apply but it doesn't if there aren't and I would like it to email me in that case as well to confirm successful execution

Answer (score 1):

In `unattended-upgrades` version `2.8`:

```
// Set this value to one of:
//    "always", "only-on-error" or "on-change"
// If this is not set, then any legacy MailOnlyOnError (boolean) value
// is used to chose between "only-on-error" and "on-change"
Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport "always";
```